# Length of HTMLCollection 0 in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I'am trying to manipulate with elements inside React component.
The problem is that the length of HTMLCollection is always 0, but in componentDidMount I expect that DOM already updated.
Why did this happen and how can I get access to elements?

```
class HTML extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var root = document.getElementById(this.props.id);
    var link = root.getElementsByTagName('a');
    console.dir(link); // several elements here
    console.log('LENGTH: ' + link.length); // but length always 0
  }

  render() {
    return (  
      <div id={this.props.id} className='html' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.data}} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging up the documentation and experiments, I rewrote everything with Callback Refs. Everything worked with this mechanism.